# Python 3.2: ./configure with PY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG

Tags: python, blackberry-10, autoconf

I'm currently trying to compile a legacy Python 3.2 for qnx-nto (aka bb10) ..

Dear StackOverFlow, I'd like to know how I may trigger;

./configure script to #define PY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG inside pyconfig.h  ..

```
Heaven:Python-3 testuser$ make
hg: no-repository, python: found! cannot run ./Parser/asdl_c.py -h ./Include ./Parser/Python.asdl
arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi-gcc -c  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -I. -IInclude -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c
In file included from Include/Python.h:50:0,
                 from ./Modules/python.c:3:
Include/pyport.h:257:13: error: #error "This platform's pyconfig.h needs to define PY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG"
Makefile:587: recipe for target 'Modules/python.o' failed
make: *** [Modules/python.o] Error 1
Heaven:Python-3 testuser$
```

Tried the following:

```
Heaven:Python-3 testuser$ ./configure -DPY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG=ll
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-DPY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG=ll'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

Comment: What is the out put of `./configure --help | grep DPY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG` ?

Comment: You might need to do something like `./configure CFLAGS=-DPY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG=ll`?

Comment: Ho yes, CFLAGS=-DPY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG=ll worked, thank you very much